# Reference a cell from another sheet to hide cells on the current worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with multiple sheets. I want to reference a cell from another sheet to hide cells on the current worksheet.

On sheet2 the logic would be something like;

If sheet1 cellA1 is equal to 3 then hide rows 20 to 30 on sheet 2

Comment: `tried things` - tried what and what happened? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Search excel vba if = https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/else-if-statement

Comment: Search excel vba hide row = https://excelchamps.com/vba/hide-unhide-column-row/

Comment: Welcome stewart! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: What will trigger the code to run ? a user action like a button click or a worksheet event.

Comment: As `cellA1 is equal to 3` will return boolean true/false, there wont be a need for an if as hidden has boolean input, so you could say `rows("1:20").entirerow.hidden=range("a1")=3`

Answer (score 1):

To set things up 'properly', you'll want to start your code with some declarations:

```
Dim mainsheet As Worksheet
Dim datasheet As Worksheet
```

Thereafter, you should set those references to the sheets in question:

```
Set datasheet = Worksheets("sheet1") ' where the test takes place
Set mainsheet = Worksheets("sheet2") ' where the rows are hidden
```

You then have some options. In your question, you ask for something that simply hides the rows if A1 = 3. You could do that with:

```
If datasheet.Range("A1").Value = 3 Then mainsheet.Rows("1:20").EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

However, once run it will never unhide if the value changes. To achieve that, you could use:

```
If datasheet.Range("A1").Value = 3 Then
    mainsheet.Rows("1:20").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
    mainsheet.Rows("1:20").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
```

The above is useful if you want to perform other tasks based on the result. If you simply want to link the row visibility to the value then you can use:

```
mainsheet.Rows("1:20").EntireRow.Hidden = (datasheet.Range("A1").Value = 3)
```

This works by resolving the `datasheet.Range("A1").Value = 3` - which will return True or False, and using that to hide/show the rows.

So the whole subroutine could look like this:

```
Sub test()

    Dim mainsheet As Worksheet
    Dim datasheet As Worksheet
    
    Set datasheet = Worksheets("sheet1") ' where the test takes place
    Set mainsheet = Worksheets("sheet2") ' where the rows are hidden
    
    mainsheet.Rows("1:20").EntireRow.Hidden = (datasheet.Range("A1").Value = 3)

End Sub
```